# Certain symmetrized product of cosines - can it be transformed into more manageable form

Tags: trigonometry, power-series, transformation, trigonometric-series, symmetric-functions

I am interested in the following expression:
$$
F_{k_1,\ldots,k_n}(t):=\sum_{\sigma\in S_n}\cos(\sigma(1)k_1t)\cos(\sigma(2)k_2t)\cdots\cos(\sigma(n)k_nt)
$$
where $k_1, \ldots, k_n$ are natural numbers (can be assumed all different) and $\sigma$ runs over the full permutation group on $\{1,...,n\}$.

Does this resemble anything simpler? I want any kind of additional information. To ask something slightly more concrete: expanding this into powers of $t$, coefficients are obviously symmetric functions of $k_1,\ldots,k_n$; they look quite impenetrable. For example,
$$
F_{k_1,k_2,k_3,k_4}(t) = 24-90s_1t^2 + \left(\frac{177}2s_1^2+96s_2\right)t^4 - \left(\frac{163}4s_1^3 + \frac{233}2s_1s_2 + 21s_3 \right)t^6 + \text{(more and more horrible fractions)},
$$
where $s_1, s_2, \ldots$ are the elementary symmetric functions of the $k_i$'s, $s_1=k_1+k_2+k_3+k_4$, $s_2=k_1k_2+k_1k_3+...+k_3k_4$, etc. How to treat this?

What would be ideal for me is a decomposition into a product of some nice terms (preferably into sums of sines or cosines, something like that).

Comment: Where you wrote $F_{k_1,k_2,k_3,k_4}(t) = \cdots$, did you have in mind some specific values of $k_1,k_2,k_3,k_4$? $\qquad$

Comment: Fixed but arbitrary. I need natural numbers but they might be just some variables too. Actually after all I have some (formal) infinite sum over all finite tuples $k_1,k_2,...,k_n$ for all $n$.

Comment: Then why don't we see $k_1,k_2,k_3,k_4$ on the right side? And where do the numbers on the right side come from? $\qquad$

Comment: On the right, elementary symmetric functions in these are present - e. g. $s_1=k_1+k_2+k_3+k_4$, etc.

Comment: I would have given the definitions of $s_1,s_2,s_3,\ldots$ in the question. $\qquad$

Comment: I've added this

Comment: It's the permanent of the matrix $A=\bigl[A_{jl}\bigr]$ with $A_{jl}=\cos(jk_l t)$. Permanents are notoriously difficult to compute.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter Thanks, did not look at it in this way. Might be that the corresponding determinant would be also relevant for my purposes. Do you find the determinant easier to evaluate?